# Excel Formula to add text/word to a percentage result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula in 1 cell

```
=(A6-B6)/B6
```

Which results to `-0.105243123560658`in cell C6. A6 has the new sales amount and B6 has the old sales amount. I'm trying to get the result formatted like:

`Difference is 10%`

I have 2 problems

- How to get the decimals turn into non-decimal number (I'm already researching on this)
- How to add a text/word to a calculation result like adding `"Difference is "` to the `(A6-B6)/B6` calculation result.

This I have tried to research and the only solution I can find involves using additional cells. Is there a way to do this with using only 1 cell ($C$6)? I tried

```
="Difference is "&(A6-B6)/B6
```

but I'm getting `Difference is -0.105243123560658` instead. Also tried:

```
="Difference is "&($B$6-$C$6)/ABS($C$6)
```

Comment: `="Difference is "&TEXT(A6/B6-1,"0%")`

Comment: @Slai this should be an answer

Comment: Or `="Difference is "&ABS(ROUNDDOWN((A6-B6)/B6 *100;0))&"%"`

Comment: @Slai it is working but can you spare more time and explain how that worked? I'm used to the formula (A6-B6)/B6 to get the percentage. Is your formula 100% accurate all the time? :D Yes you should post this as an answer.

Comment: The question seems off-topic to me (check the description of the excel tag), but you can check the [`TEXT` function documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c). `(A6-B6)/B6` is the same as `A6/B6-B6/B6` and `B6/B6` is 1

Comment: @Slai Excel Formulas are generally considered a form of programming on SO, so the subject is on topic.  OP has told us his objective, what he's tried and where it went wrong, so overall it satisfies the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You need the TEXT function:

```
="Difference is "&TEXT(ABS(A6-B6)/B6,"0%")
```